# curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace at pos 2

Tags: json, bash, curl

I keep receiving this error :     `curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace at pos 2`
and I don't even understand where is "pos 2"
Although strangely I don't have the same problem when I do that from bash. I run that code in Jenkins pipeline. That is why you see sh '''' wrapper

```
sh '''
    curl  -u ${GIT_USERNAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD} -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://tools.company.my.com/bitbucket/rest/build-status/1.0/commits/$GIT_COMMIT --data-binary @- <<BODY \
            {
              "state": "SUCCESSFUL",
              "key": "$JOB_BASE_NAME",
              "name": "$BUILD_TAG",
              "url": "$BUILD_URL",
              "description": "change"
            }
            BODY
               '''
```

Comment: why th backslash at the end of first line? otherwise because of `<<BODY`, `BODY` must be directly at the start of the line

Comment: What's the point of triple apostrophes for the shell? These should probably be single apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no single quote in ${GIT_PASSWORD} :

```
sh -c "curl -u '${GIT_USERNAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}'\
            -H 'Content-Type: application/json'\
            -X POST 'https://tools.company.my.com/bitbucket/rest/build-status/1.0/commits/$GIT_COMMIT'\
            --data-binary @-" << BODY
            {
              "state": "SUCCESSFUL",
              "key": "$JOB_BASE_NAME",
              "name": "$BUILD_TAG",
              "url": "$BUILD_URL",
              "description": "change"
            }
BODY
```

Comment: I needed that because of Jenkins